# Bazel - What is the relation between hdrs vs includes on a cc_library to generate gcc command with -I instead of -isystem or -iquote?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

Looks like there is a relation between creating a `cc_library` on a `BUILD` file using `hdrs` and `includes` to generate the `gcc` command with `-isystem`, `-iquote` and `-I`.

[Official Bazel doc](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.include_prefix)

To explain my problem better, I have this example.

I have a `Bazel` project with the following files:

- main.cpp
- WORKSPACE
- BUILD

The dependencies are:

1. `main.cpp` needs `foo.hpp`
2. `foo.hpp` needs access to `#include "bar.h"`, so a library `hdrs-bar` is provided
3. `bar.h` needs access to `#include <system_bar.h>`, so a library `hdrs-system-bar` is provided. (Note that `<>` on the include is needed.)
4. A binary called `demo` is created with all these dependencies

As described on (1), the `main.cpp` contains:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

int main()
{
    // ...something which uses foo.hpp
    return 0;
}
```

As described on (2), to be able to access `foo.hpp` from `main.cpp` I need to create a Bazel project out of a git repository and create a `BUILD` file for for it using the `build_file_content` where it contains a library that will expose all the `*.h` files I need (including the `bar.h`).

Therefore the WORKSPACE file contains:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "new_git_repository")

new_git_repository(
    name = "bar-utils",
    remote = "https://github.com/someGitRepo/bar-utils.git",
    branch = "master",
    build_file_content = """

       package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
       cc_library(
           name = "hdrs-bar",
           hdrs = glob(["bar/*.h"], allow_empty=False),
           strip_include_prefix = "bar",
      )

""",
)
```

As described on (3), the `WORKSPACE` file also contains a creation of a library called `hdrs-system-bar` which contains the system headers needed from `bar.h`:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "bar-system",
    path = "/usr/local/bar/include",
    build_file_content = """
        cc_library(
          name = "hdrs-system-bar",
          hdrs = glob(["*.h"], allow_empty=False),
          visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
        )    
""",    
)
```

As described in (4), the BUILD file contains a binary which gets all the dependencies in `deps`:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "demo",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = ["@bar-utils//:hdrs-bar", "@bar-system//:hdrs-system-bar"],
)
```

If I compile:

```
$ bazel build //... --sandbox_debug
```

I get the following build **ERROR**:

```
bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/external/bar-utils/_virtual_includes/hdrs-bar/barUtils.h:7:10: fatal error: bar_runtime.h: No such file or directory #include <bar_runtime.h>
```

The file `bar_runtime.h` should be inside the library `hdrs-system-bar`.
So if I see my sandbox folder on `.../sandbox/linux-sandbox/4/execroot/__main__/` I get the following directories:

- main.cpp
- bazel-out
- external

On the `external`, I have these two folder, where each contains all the header files I need:

- bar-utils
- bar-system

On the `bazel-out`, I have the following:

```
aarch64-fastbuild/bin/external/bar-utils/_virtual_includes/hdrs-bar/bar.h
```

I was expecting inside this `bazel-out` `external` to have also the `bar-system`, but there is only `bar-utils`. Why is that?

To add more info the gcc command generated was like this (removed all the non-necessary arguments for sake of simplicity):

```
/usr/bin/gcc -iquote external/bar-utils -iquote external/bar-system -c main.cpp
```

If I simply use includes instead of hdrs on all the libraries creation, I get a lot of `-isystem` instead of the `-iquote`. But what I need is actually the `-I<folder where the headers are>`.

If I manually change my gcc command to:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -iquote external/bar-utils -Iexternal/bar-system -c main.cpp
```

Then it works.

How can I force it to use `-I`? Changing the `cc_libraries` to `srcs` or `includes` instead of `hdrs` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to also use the `includes` flag, besides the hdrs. This way it will show up on the sandbox and be accessible by adding the `-isystem` argument for gcc with the folder you need.

```
    cc_library(
      name = "hdrs-system-bar",
      hdrs = glob(["*.h"], allow_empty=False),
      includes = ["."],
      visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    )
```

Comment: Note that the attribute is `includes` and not `include` per the Bazel documentation: https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp